# Sinatra only recognizing first GET param

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have a simple Sinatra app. When I do:

```
curl localhost:4567/api/shows?limit=1&page=2
```

I only see this in the Sinatra log:

```
{"limit"=>"1"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @thang ? i know i am probably making a stupid/carless mistake. please just tell me

Answer (score 2):

I need quotes around the url in curl. So it would be:

```
curl 'localhost:4567/api/shows?limit=1&page=2'
```

Reason: `&` means run whatever you typed before it as a command in the background, that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: Correct, but do you understand why?